# Select Male & Female's names from the same table Contacts

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is My 'Contacts' table.

```
| Names      |   Gender   |

| Mike       | Male       |
| Steve      | Male       |
| Kelly      | Female     |
| Jane       | Female     |
| Natasha    | Female     |
| Mathew     | Male       |
| Jack       | Male       |
```

I want result like that:

```
|  Male      |   Female   |   

| Mike       | Kelly      |
| Steve      | Jane       |
| Mathew     | Natasha    |
| Jack       |            |
```

please give me solution to achieve this result in SQL Sever...
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How or why is "Mike" paired with "Kelly"? Why is "Jack" not paired with any result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with Male as
(
  select Names,
         row_number() over(order by Names) as rn
  from YourTable
  where Gender = 'Male'
),
Female as
(
  select Names,
         row_number() over(order by Names) as rn
  from YourTable
  where Gender = 'Female'
)
select Male.Names as Male,
       Female.Names as Female
from Male
  full outer join Female
    on Male.rn = Female.rn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1da92/2/0)

Not the exact result you want but as good as it gets without another column to order by.

```
Male    Female
------- -------
Jack    Jane
Mathew  Kelly
Mike    Natasha
Steve   NULL
```